# Window to detect a file being dragged over it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, event-handling

The goal is not to drag a file into a window, but detect when something is (trying) to be dragged into (or above) the window. How could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to go about this, but broadly speaking you are talking about 'collision detection'.

Assuming the WINDOW is not moving, you know it's frame and that won't change.
Assuming you can already drag an OBJECT around, you know where the user originally touched the OBJECT, both with respect to itself and it's superview. You also know how far the user has dragged it and to where, since the touch has moved to a new destination.

Since you know all of the above, you can calculate if the visible size of the OBJECT you are dragging has reached the frame of the WINDOW or not.